# Changing Firebase app key in keystore

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am in the process of learning Firebase authentication by developing an Android application that will implement Facebook login as one of the authentication methods.

While configuring the Firebase project, I am sure that I used my personal password for the key store. After reading and watching a couple of tutorials and looking through the documentation, I noticed that people are using "android" as the key store password.

Will I need to go back and change my key store password to "android"?

Is it possible to change the password once it is saved?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably seeing others only use the `debug.keystore`, wherein the default password is Android. This is commonly used for signing debug builds. If you used your own keystore, then most probably that the correct password is the one you already used.

<sub>More details can be found about App Signing [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)</sub>

Long story short, using the `debug.keystore` is not required or anything.

Comment: So I'm curious will there be a problem if I use the two different passwords? Or should I just use the same one as I did when I set up the Firebase project initially?